# Hide Done Backlog Items on TFS Task Board

Tags: team-foundation-server

Many of our development teams don't work in conventional sprints, since their work is delivered on an ad-hoc basis. To accommodate these teams in the portfolio, we created a single sprint for them with no iteration dates in TFS 2013.

However, I've noticed that PBIs aren't removed from the Task Board when their status is set to *Done*. This creates a scenario on the task board where we have an increasing number of done tasks, and we will eventually arrive at a state where we can't display all our work on the task board due to the item limit.

Is there a way to prevent PBIs in the "Done" state from appearing on the task board? (Note that I'm specifically referring to the Task Board, not the backlog.)